# Why did HTML 5 drop support for setting iframe height in %?

Tags: html, css, iframe

[In HTML 4.01, the height could be defined in pixels or in % of the containing element. In HTML5, the value must be in pixels.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_height.asp)

Why was this decision made? Is there some concern that setting `height: 100%;` will have some negative consequence? It's not like people can't set `height: 100000px;` (obviously, not a good work around).

Is there some sort of reference someone can give me to the reasoning behind this?

I'm not sure this will be regarded as a good question for this forum, if you think this question isn't appropriate here, please recommend a better place to ask.

I suppose one might phrase this differently, ***What are the disadvantages of applying height as a percent to an iframe in HTML 4.01?*** (other than the fact that HTML 4.01 is obsolete)

Comment: I also have the same question, no explanation here either: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_height.asp

Comment: Maybe you should broaden your search from just w3schools.com... Also, you can specify the height of the `iframe` in CSS using percentage, just not in the `height` attribute of the element. See also, for 100%: [HTML5 iframe relative size](//stackoverflow.com/q/13209531)

Comment: iframes do not respect style="height:100%;" It's not limited to the height attribute, it seems to apply to the style as well.

Answer (score 2):

The 'dropped support' that you are referencing is only through use of the inline `height` attribute. This was dropped because inline attributes mix content and styling, which is bad practice; your markup should be completely separated from its presentation.

**[`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)** elements can indeed take up `100%` of the height of their parent, although they are `inline` elements by default.

What's important to remember is that with percentage-driven values, these are relative to the **immediate** parent. If the immediate parent doesn't have a `height`, the element won't inherit their `height` automatically from a grandparent (or higher):

```css
div.outer {
  background: cyan;
  height: 300px;
}

iframe {
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

This can be resolved by ensureing that every element in between the element with a **fixed** `height` and the target element with the percentage-based `height` all have `height: 100%` set as well:

```css
div.outer {
  background: cyan;
  height: 300px;
}

div.inner {
  height: 100%;
}

iframe {
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML5 Section 4.7.19. Dimension attributes](https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#sec-dimension-attributes) says

> Author requirements: The width and height attributes on img, iframe, embed, object, video, and, when their type attribute is in the Image Button state, input elements may be specified to give the dimensions of the visual content of the element (the width and height respectively, relative to the nominal direction of the output medium), in CSS pixels. The attributes, if specified, must have values that are valid non-negative integers.
>
> [...]
>
> **The two attributes must be omitted if the resource in question does not have both an intrinsic width and an intrinsic height.**

That is, it is only valid to use height and width in pixels when the resource in the iframe has an intrinsic width and an intrinsic height. And the height and width should reflect those intrinsic dimensions. So it makes no sense for them to be specified in percentages because intrinsic dimensions aren't in percentages.

Percentages are always just styling. So they should be specified in CSS, not HTML.